# How to style Button in RemoteViews when create android app widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview, android-remoteview

I want to create a simple widget with some Icon Button. As we all know, only some simple view can be used in RemoteViews, so I try to style Button like this:

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/leave_sheet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?attr/materialIconButtonFilledTonalStyle"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_delete_24"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Android Studio layout preview is OK
[image]

But when I run the app, the icon doesn't show up.
[image]

how to solve this problem?
Or is there any way to achieve Material You style Icon Button in app widget like Google Drive & Google Keep?
[image]